# Tesseract "_OBJC_CLASS_$_G8Tesseract", referenced from:

Tags: ios, tesseract

<<< xcode linker error message >>>

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_G8Tesseract", referenced from:objc-class-ref in CalendarViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

<<< import header file >>>

import "TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.h"

<<< podfile >>>

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'toeicMap' do

pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', :git => 'https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS.git'

end

<<< pod install message >>>

hirata-MacBook-Pro:myMap+pod hirata$ pod install

Analyzing dependencies

Downloading dependencies

Installing TesseractOCRiOS 4.0.0 (was 3.4.0)

Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.

[!] The `toeicMap [Debug]` target overrides the `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-toeicMap/Pods-toeicMap.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `toeicMap [Release]` target overrides the `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-toeicMap/Pods-toeicMap.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
hirata-MacBook-Pro:myMap+pod hirata$

<<< Target Support Files/Pods-toeicMap/Pods-toeicMap.debug.xcconfig >>>

CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = compiler-default
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/TesseractOCRiOS"
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/TesseractOCRiOS" $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR/lib"
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/TesseractOCRiOS"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -weak_library /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib -l"TesseractOCRiOS" -l"lept" -l"stdc++" -l"tesseract_all" -framework "Foundation" -framework "UIKit"
PODS_BUILD_DIR = $BUILD_DIR
PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = $PODS_BUILD_DIR/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods

pod version = 1.0.1

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your post is just a debud dump. Can you describe what exactly is your problem and keep the debugger code in adequate {code} style ? The way your post is right now makes it very hard to read and understand :|